# Inline::Python tunneling mode

Tags: comments, raku

My raku Inline::Python code module unexpectedly prints output even when the rs_str method is disabled.

```
use Inline::Python;

role Series {
    has $args;
    has $!py = Inline::Python.new;
    has $.po;                     #each instance has own Python Series obj

    method TWEAK {

my $py-str = qq{

class RakuSeries:
    def __init__(self):
        self.series = pd.Series($args)

#`[
    def rs_str(self):
        return(str(self.series))
#]

};

        $!py.run($py-str);
        $!po = $!py.call('__main__', 'RakuSeries');
    }

    method Str {
        $!po.rs_str()
    }
}

say ~Series.new( args => "[1, 3, 5, 6, 8]" );

>>>
0    1
1    3
2    5
3    6
4    8
Name: anon, dtype: int64
```

Is this a special tunnelling mode?

Comment: You do realize the `#\`[` is just an ordinary line in a multi-line string in your Raku code, and just a one-line comment when that multi-line string is interpreted in Python, right? (So it's not "commenting out" the `rs_str` function definition if that's what you're thinking.)

Comment: @raiph - sorry couldn't resist this as an -Ofun April Fool (although I really did wonder why it was working despite the commenting out for about 10 mins, which prompted me to post it since I realized I had been such an a**!!) - I owe you a beer!

Comment: Hah! I had even thought stuff like "Why hasn't he created an [MRE]? Should I write an answer? Should I downvote the Q?" And I did vote to close. So you totally got me. :) I think part of it was that I only saw the Q on the 2nd and didn't even think to look at the time you posted it. But in retrospect it's a perfectly executed prank. Q now duly and happily upvoted! 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poisson d'Avril
April Fool
першоквітневий дурень
Aprilscherz